# Ruby gem tensorflow.rb example not working

Tags: ruby, tensorflow

I am trying to run the ruby tensorflow example.rb file, as described [here](https://medium.com/@Arafat./introducing-tensorflow-ruby-api-e77a477ff16e#.41r68bki7). I have installed tensorflow.rb using docker, as described [here](https://github.com/somaticio/tensorflow.rb).  When I run `bundle exec rspec spec`, all examples pass.

I have created a file `example.rb` as instructed. When I run the file using `ruby example.rb`, I get the following error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ruby-tensorflow/gems/tensorflow-0.0.1/lib/tensorflow/session.rb:168:in `graph_def_to_c_array': undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ruby-tensorflow/gems/tensorflow-0.0.1/lib/tensorflow/session.rb:51:in `extend_graph'
    from example.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

When I run each line of `example.rb` in an irb session, the error occurs at the command:

```
session.extend_graph(graph)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi Obromios, I'm one of the contributors in this project – still very much in alpha-stage! Did you use the latest version, since [`lib/tensorflow/session.rb:168`](https://github.com/somaticio/tensorflow.rb/blob/master/lib/tensorflow/session.rb#L168) is actually a blank line? 
I just ran `ruby example.rb` (I put `example.rb` in the root of the project folder, same level as `Gemfile`) and it outputs `[[-4.0, 4.2, 9.5], [10.0, 6.3, 10.1]]` – the sum of the two tensors.

Comment: There is something strange with the version. I have used the command ```docker run -it nethsix/ruby-tensorflow-ubuntu:0.0.1.a /bin/bash``` to start the process,  which I assume uses the 0.0.1.a version of the gem, but if you look at the above error message, it is citing the 0.0.1 version. Maybe there is something wrong with the docker package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was raised as [an issue](https://github.com/somaticio/tensorflow.rb/issues/72). It turned out that the docker image was out of date. It has been fixed, so if you follow the new Readme instructions, then it now all works.